# Store and alter single variable on vercel serverless functions

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, serverless, vercel

For a client I am building a static website rendered with nextjs and deployed on vercel. Everything on this website is static, so I don't need any database. However, this client wants to use the instagram API to show a gallery of their photos on two of their pages. This is with a custom design, so I can't use any embed code, but to the best of my knowledge I have to use the Instagram basic display API

To the problem at hand: I was wondering if there is some way to store a single variable without creating a whole database for it in vercel. I know I can use Environment Variables, but the problem is that the instagram api needs to change the access token every 2 months. To renew the access token for instagram, I was planning to write a CRON job that runs about every month to update this value.

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow store this single value on the deployed site without creating a database just for this single value. For example, is it somehow possible to change an environment variable from within a serverless function?

Any help in the right direction is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You go to Vercel: settings-> environment variables -> add your variable. In this variable you can store your `Instagram API variable` and in the code you use `process.env.{variable}`

Example:

1. you defined `name` of variable as `instagramAPI` in your `local files` (`next.config.js` or `.env.local`)

   ```
   module.exports = {
      env:{
         instagramAPI : 'https://instagramapiexample.com'
      },
   }
   ```
2. you define `instagramAPI` (exactly the same name of the variable as in the code) on your `vercel settings`
3. In your code (local files) you call `process.env.instagramAPI` variable to have the value of the string.
4. Your code works as expected.

!IMPORTANT! if you have some `secrets` or `passwords` in your `process.env.variables` you newer saves it in next.config.js. For this purpose you saves your `instagramAPI` to .env.local (described in point 1). More [info here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

Comment: Thanks!, but my question was about changing the variables. I know how to read environment variables. I was wondering if there is some way I can set (change) an environment variable from within a serverless function

Comment: As I know, there is no possible ways to set it from the code (for Vercel part)